# Replace with change position with Php function for Local language to Unicode

Tags: php, unicode, position, str-replace, strpos

eg.  **AcF  to cFA**
Here  AcF is **other language and output** is cFA  it's UNICODE.

when we write AcF then it must I have to write like  cFA then its output in browser will the same ... AcF but it is now unicode...

**hits... unicode write as pronounce...** eg..

```
$str  = str_replace("","&amp;#2744;&amp;#2765;&amp;#2719;&amp;#2751;",$str); // સ્ટિ  

સ &rarr; &amp;#2744; ્&rarr; &amp;#2765; ટ &rarr; &amp;#2719; િ &rarr; &amp;#2751;



  Find 
  is other language so its write like..... 
1st chr is  િ   
2nd chr is સ્   (half character)
3rd chr is  ટ       

Replace
1st chr is  સ્    સ = &amp;#2744; ્= &amp;#2765; 
2nd chr is  ટ = &amp;#2719; 
3rd chr is  િ = &amp;#2751;
```

***NOW.... I WANT SOLUTION with function LIKE***

```
Find 
  is other language so its write like..... 
1st chr is  િ   
2nd chr is Anyhalf character
3rd chr is  AnyFull character       

Replace
1st chr is  Anyhalf character
2nd chr is  AnyFull character
3rd chr is  િ
```

I also added at top [meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"]
and save file with Encoding Utf-8.

I spent 30hr for solution but fail. I hope some one help me...
Thank You.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please proofread and properly format your questions. You will get help much more easily if you put more effort in describing your problem.

Comment: Next time I will advance take care for your suggestion thanks Petezurich.